# SQL Union Query Count to different Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I could use some help. I have a query that counts the number of Fault Codes using a Case and Like statement, with a Where clause on date.  I then union it with a secondary query.  Only difference is the date. It works but returns the values in

```
    Fault Code     Count
    20k            71
    60k            167
    20k            86
    60k           178
```

It returns the secondary count under the 'Count' Column.  However, I want to add another column.  Example:

```
    Fault Code    CountA     CountB
    20k           71         86
    60k           167        178
```

Any suggestions?  Do I create a temp table?

Here is my code.

```
    SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '60%' THEN '60k'
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '20%' THEN '20k'
    END AS FaultCode
    , COUNT(FaultCode) AS Day1
    FROM RmaSummary 
    Where CreationTime > '2016-03-30' AND CreationTIme < '2016-03-31' AND
    ClosedTime Is null AND (FaultCode LIKE '60%' OR FaultCode LIKE '20%')
    AND FaultCode <> '20000' AND FaultCode <> '60052' AND FaultCode <> '0'
    GROUP BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '60%' THEN '60k' 
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '20%' THEN '20k' 
    END 
    Union All
    SELECT 
    CASE
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '60%' THEN '60k'
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '20%' THEN '20k'
    END AS FaultCode
    , COUNT(FaultCode) AS Day2
    FROM RmaSummary 
    Where CreationTime > '2016-03-31' AND CreationTIme < '2016-04-01' AND 
    ClosedTime Is null AND (FaultCode LIKE '60%' OR FaultCode LIKE '20%') 
    AND FaultCode <> '20000' AND FaultCode <> '60052' AND FaultCode <> '0'
    GROUP BY 
    CASE 
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '60%' THEN '60k' 
    WHEN FaultCode LIKE '20%' THEN '20k' 
    END
```

Comment: Use PIVOT to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Conditional Aggregation` instead of `UNION` which will get you the result in expected format.

This will count the records only when `faultcode` fall with in the given date range

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN faultcode LIKE '60%' THEN '60k' 
         WHEN faultcode LIKE '20%' THEN '20k' 
       END        AS FaultCode, 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN creationtime > '2016-03-30' 
                    AND creationtime < '2016-03-31' THEN faultcode 
             END) AS Day1, 
       Count(CASE 
               WHEN creationtime > '2016-03-31' 
                    AND creationtime < '2016-04-01' THEN faultcode 
             END) AS Day2 
FROM   rmasummary 
WHERE  closedtime IS NULL 
       AND ( faultcode LIKE '60%' 
              OR faultcode LIKE '20%' ) 
       AND faultcode <> '20000' 
       AND faultcode <> '60052' 
       AND faultcode <> '0' 
GROUP  BY CASE 
        WHEN faultcode LIKE '60%' THEN '60k' 
        WHEN faultcode LIKE '20%' THEN '20k' 
      END
```

Comment: @EMIE - Glad that the answer helped you. Please accept the answer by clicking on tick symbol on left of the answer so it could be closed. Thanks.